# I need to know what to put for my app can be installed on external memory

Tags: java, android

As android application developer, I need to know what to put for my app can be installed on external memory.

Many applications are possible install on the SD card, but my app is not possible. someone knows to be configured for it.

Thank you.!

Comment: I found out the hard way that if your app contains a widget, it is not possible. (at least not if you want the widget to work...) There's also something in the XML Manifest that can prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:installLocation="preferExternal"`, or another value for `android:installLocation`, to your root `<manifest>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, as is described in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html).

Please also read carefully the ["Applications That Should NOT Install on External Storage" section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot), as it may be that your app should not be installed to external storage.

And, also bear in mind that since this is no longer relevant as of Android 3.0, you may not want to bother with it at this point.

Comment: Why is this no longer relevant as of Android 3.0?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Because the split between internal and external storage went away. In Android 1.x/2.x, internal and external storage had to be on separate partitions. That's no longer the case, and most devices have them on the same partition, just in separate directories. That way, the full X MB of storage is available to files wherever they are stored. The reason for the so-called "install-to-SD" capability was due to internal storage being cramped on older Android devices, which is now no longer an issue.

Comment: @CommonsWare i don't understand. you mean that apps cannot be installed into the external storage anymore? also, if they can, only the apk is saved there, right? the private data is still stored in the internal storage for safe keeping...

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "you mean that apps cannot be installed into the external storage anymore?" -- the whole option is ignored by the installer, near as I can tell. For example, you can't move things between internal and external anymore. The manifest entry is OK, it just won't have any particular benefit. "the private data is still stored in the internal storage for safe keeping" -- internal storage is unaffected by "install-to-SD" and would be wherever it is naturally.

Comment: @CommonsWare do apps automatically get installed on the external storage when the internal storage is low on free space? is there an API for putting existing apps into the external storage (from the internal storage) , even the existing app?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "do apps automatically get installed on the external storage when the internal storage is low on free space?" -- that's up to the firmware and may vary. "is there an API for putting existing apps into the external storage (from the internal storage) , even the existing app?" -- no.